# set space between rows in listview Android

Tags: android

I have a listView with custom rows and I need to set a custom divider between each row.
This is the code of the listView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/menu_padding"
android:background="@color/customBlue"
android:divider="@drawable/list_divider" 
android:dividerHeight="2px" />
```

This is the code of the rows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
tools:ignore="contentDescription"
android:background="@color/strongBlue" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/row_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code for the 2 pixel divider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:bottom="1px">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                    android:color="#0C0832"
                    android:width="2dp"
                    />
            <size
                    android:height="1px"
                    />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="1px">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                    android:color="#2D2E57"
                    android:width="2dp"
                    />
            <size
                    android:height="1px"
                    />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The problem is that I have a random space between each row that has the same color as the listView backgroundColor and if I set the dividerHeight to 4px I can see my divider. How can I remove the space that gets created automatically and only have my custom divider?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pixel you can provide dp in `xml`

```
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:divider="#ffffff"


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">; 

<gradient 

android:type="radial" 
android:startColor="#343030"
 android:endColor="#151515" 
android:gradientRadius="300" 
android:angle="270" 
android:centerY="0.3"/> 

</shape>
```

Instead of making custom drawable for divider you can directly give color to  divider.

Comment: I need to have 2 different colors on the divider, that's why I had to adopt that solution

Comment: you can  use gradient for two colors

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
            android:type="radial"
            android:startColor="#343030"
            android:endColor="#151515"
            android:gradientRadius="300"
            android:angle="270"
            android:centerY="0.3"/>
</shape>

Comment: You might use a `drawable` with gradient

Comment: use this for adding diffrent colors

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in rows in linear layout

```
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
```

Comment: Keep height as wrap content and then give the margin